# Check if list contains a type?

Tags: python

What is the fastest way I can check for a certain types existence in a list?

I wish I could do the following:

```
class Generic(object)
    ... def ...
class SubclassOne(Generic)
    ... def ...
class SubclassOne(Generic)
    ... def ...

thing_one = SubclassOne()
thing_two = SubclassTwo()
list_of_stuff = [thing_one, thing_two]

if list_of_stuff.__contains__(SubclassOne):
    print "Yippie!"
```

EDIT: Trying to stay within the python 2.7 world. But 3.0 solutions will be ok!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`if any(isinstance(x, SubclassOne) for x in list_of_stuff):`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

```
if any(isinstance(item, SubClassOne) for item in list_of_stuff):
    print "Yippie!"
```