# Extracting only single tags in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for a way to extract only tags that don't have another tag in it

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<p><a href='XYZ'>Text1</a></p>
<p>Text2</p>
<p><a href='QWERTY'>Text3</a></p>
<p>Text4</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('p')
```

Gives

```
[<p><a href="XYZ">Text1</a></p>,
 <p>Text2</p>,
 <p><a href="QWERTY">Text3</a></p>,
 <p>Text4</p>]
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[<p>Text2</p>,
 <p>Text4</p>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `Tag`s without other tags in them as follows:

```python
for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    if isinstance(tag.next, str):
        print(tag)
```

Which returns

```html
<p>Text2</p>
<p>Text4</p>
```

Comment: It works for the provided example, but not for that what is asked for. 
Using `.next` would not take care filtering out tags if a string is positioned before a tag in the html. See my contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply filter it afterwards using `if/else` on the length of the tags, if it's only `p` then it'll be empty, otherwise it will get filtered out:

```
for x in soup.find_all('p'):
    if len([x.tag for x in x.find_all()]) == 0:
        print(x)
```

Returns only:

```
<p>Text2</p>
<p>Text4</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p><a href='XYZ'>Text1</a></p>
<p>Text2</p>
<p><a href='QWERTY'>Text3</a></p>
<p>Text4</p>
<p>Text6: <a href='QWERTY'>Text5</a></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def p_tag_with_only_strings_as_children(tag):
    return tag.name == "p" and all(isinstance(x, str) for x in tag.children)

result = soup.find_all(p_tag_with_only_strings_as_children)

print(result)
```

Result:

```
[<p>Text2</p>, <p>Text4</p>]
```

[BeautifulSoup-Documentation for using function-filters on .find_all().](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=has_attr#a-function)

For checking for types within a list credits go to.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705845/5288820.

---

Or use CSS-Selectors:
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p><a href='XYZ'>Text1</a></p>
<p>Text2</p>
<p><a href='QWERTY'>Text3</a></p>
<p>Text4</p>
<p>Text6: <a href='QWERTY'>Text5</a></p>
""".replace('\n',"")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select('p:not(:has(*))'))
#or in case you only want to filter out "a" tags:
print(soup.select('p:not(:has(a))'))
```

Result:

```
[<p>Text2</p>, <p>Text4</p>]
```